# How to pass argument to subject in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec3

I have one subject block that I want to reuse in various places.

```
subject(:stubbed_data) do
  expect(response.body).to eq(dynamic_var)
end
```

The `dynamic_var` variable will be different for different test cases. Is there any way to call `subbed_data` subject with arguments so that I can have dynamic value for `dynamic_var` variable?

Answer (score 20):

You're not supposed to pass arguments to `subject`. And, by the way, it's a wrong place to make assertions (things like `expect`), they need to be done inside `it` blocks.
However, you can define (and redefine) your dependencies inside `let` blocks, like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :arg
  def initialize(arg)
    @arg = arg
  end
end

RSpec.describe MyClass do
  subject { MyClass.new(dynamic) }
  let(:dynamic) { 'default value' }

  context 'it works with default value' do
    it { expect(subject.arg).to eq 'default value' }
  end
  context 'it works with dynamic value' do
    let(:dynamic) { 'dynamic value' }
    it { expect(subject.arg).to eq 'dynamic value' }
  end
end
```

Comment: What if you're trying to test a class method that you can't initialize, and want to test many different inputs for?